# Destroying php object references

Tags: php, object-reference

I will try to be succinct on this:

I have this:

Example1:

```
$obj1 = new SimpleObj();
$obj2 = $obj1;
$obj2 = null;
```

Example2:

```
$obj1 = new SimpleObj();
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
$obj2 = null;
```

Example3:

```
$obj1 = new SimpleObj();
$obj2 =& $obj1;
$obj2 = null;
```

I did a lot of research on this, but i'm not assured yet.
Which one will actually destroy the object and free memory?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Destroy which object? Examples 1 and 2 destroy $obj2, and example 3 destroys $obj1 by destroying $obj2 which references to it.

Comment: PHP is a garbage collected language. You have no control over when memory is freed. If you just want to know when an object is destroyed you can add the `__destruct` function to your class. It will be called when then object is destroyed.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you [best way to destroy php object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798443/best-way-to-destroy-php-object#answers-header)

Comment: In example 1 - you destroy the variable $obj2 that contain the address to the object. same goes for example 2. in example 3 you destroy $obj1 because $obj2 value is the address of $obj1 due to the &