# Does PHP garbage collect function-scoped objects after a call returns?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, phpunit

I know that once a script ends, [all objects are destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798460/4233593) and memory is returned. Does this also happen to function-scoped objects once the function ends that aren't accessible anyway?

For instance, I'm worried about memory leaks in my PHPUnit tests, wherein I create a new object for almost every test. Will this eventually overflow my heap if I run enough tests?

```
public function testMyFunction()
{
    // Arrange
    $myObject = new MyClass();

    // Act
    $return = $myObject->myFunction();

    // Assert
    $this->assertEquals(true, $return);

}
```

Should I be manually `unset`ting them for long-running scripts in an "Absterge" section?

```
public function testMyFunction()
{
    // Arrange
    $myObject = new MyClass();

    // Act
    $return = $myObject->myFunction();

    // Assert
    $this->assertEquals(true, $return);

    // Absterge
    unset($myObject);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP will garbage collect once all references to an object are gone.

`unset` is not needed. However, it is possible that you have a circular dependency, in which case it might not get garbage collected.

The only reason for using `unset()` is if you'd like to free memory *before* the end of the function. If there's still something else holding a reference to the thing that you're unsetting, unset() only removes the local variable, but not the object itself.

There's a special garbage collection cycle that cleans up as well circular references. You can control this with this php.ini setting:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.zend.enable-gc

If you are interested in testing when and if your objects get garbage collected, you could add a `__destruct` method.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to circle back to testing your answer. using the `__destruct` method to test was the obvious insight I'd missed. thanks!!