# PHP Destructor | unset() VS overwriting object

Tags: php, object, memory, destructor

I have learned from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798443/best-way-to-destroy-php-object) that the best way to destroy objects in PHP is to use `unset`.

I am wondering if I even need to destroy the object if I am essentially using the same var in a loop ...

```
foreach ($ids_array as $id) {
    $O = new Object($id);

    // stuff and things
}
```

Does this really use the same memory or am I unknowingly creating a bunch of objects and not destroying them?

Comment: You overwrite `$O` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no variable left referring to an object, it will eventually get garbage collected. For that purpose it's irrelevant whether you `unset` the variable(s) or simply assign something else to them so they stop referring to the object.

IMO you should rarely use `unset`, you should rather write *small functions* which will automatically discard all variables in their scope when they return, which means things will get garbage collected automatically rather sooner than later and you don't need to worry much about it.